# Changing the type of value in JSONB column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, casting, jsonb

I have the 'subject' column of JSONB type that stores JSON objects. Examples: `{"team": "1234", "user": 5678}` or `{"org": 123}` or {"team": 1234}.

What query should I use to change all the occurrences of {"team": "1234", ...} to {"team": 1234, ...}?

I tried:

```
UPDATE the_table SET subject = jsonb_set(subject, '{team}', (subject->>'team')::int)
```

but i get:

```
ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 2: SET subject = jsonb_set(subject, 'team', (subject->>'team'):... 
                      ^ 
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No this will empty the second record: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7bc80bef9b7dc68b893d78a96cd8105f

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Please have a look at the fiddle. Isn't it as you meant. This results in an empty result if "team" is not found in the json (see second example record)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast the `subject->>'team'` result directly into `jsonb` instead of `int`. Don't forget to add a WHERE filter because otherwise your second record will be deleted.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=37f0f3c062f6c33e065cf167f8e65c21)

```
UPDATE the_table 
SET subject = jsonb_set(subject, '{team}', (subject->>'team')::jsonb)
WHERE subject->>'team' IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: alternatively  `where subject ? 'team'`

Comment: Ok, that works. But why? Originally at `subject.team` there were strings and after casting to JSONB suddenly there are ints. I don't understand it.

Comment: ->> gives out the text representation of the value, without any " chars. If you cast this directly into a json you get the without-"-representation which, in fact, is json. You approach war the right one. The only disadvantage was that your valid int cast results... in an int. This is not accepted as parameter type. So you could have cast it into ::text::jsonb afterwards.. or do it directly